# How to automatically choose a default AzureAD authentication provider from IdentityServer4?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, identityserver4

Want to enable multiple Authentication provider against AzureAD from IdentityServer4.  (Something like reference: [Enable multiple AzureAd in Identityserver4 .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47692311/enable-multiple-azuread-in-identityserver4-net-core))

The reason for this behavior is depending on the web client application each will need to authenticate against different AzureAD client app, with different in-app roles defined using the Manifest setting in AzureAD.

(So this has been done.)

The other problem is instead of providing multiple authentication options for users when logging in via IdentityServer4, would like to automatically choose one of the multiple AzureAD authentication options based on a configuration setting per web client app.

Is this easily feasible with IdentityServer4, or already available?

Comment: Did you manage to do it?  I managed to pass the acr_values, but Idsrv 4 is still not redirecting to external provider automatically

Answer (score 1):

The authorize endpoint has an **acr_values** attribute that accepts idp-value in **idp:name_of_idp** format (see it at the very bottom of the page) 
http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/endpoints/authorize.html

Say you have this in your **IdentityServer Startup**

```
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", "OpenID Connect", options =>
{
    // ..
    // Your serverside configuration here
    // ..
});
```

And this is your **Mvc Core client Startup**

```
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
{
    // ..
    // Your client side configuration here
    // ..
    options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = n =>
    {
        n.ProtocolMessage.AcrValues = "idp:oidc"; // Refers to the oidc scheme in Server's startup

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    };
});
```

Now, if you want to access a secured endpoint with the client, 
the authorization redirect will generate an url something like this:

> https://...?client_id=...&redirect_uri=...&response_type=...&scope=...&response_mode=...&nonce=...&***acr_values=idp:oidc***&state=...&x-client-SKU=...&x-client-ver=...

This will skip the IdentityServer's login page and redirect to the selected external Idp.

If the client applications are not written by you, and you have to specify the external identity provider on serverside, 
based on the client, then it could be a little tricky, and I don't remember this feature is natively supported by IdentityServer. I think you have to implement this kind of logic by yourself **after** client validation is successful.
I would go with a redirect to login page with appended acr_values solution, to minimize my code and maximize built-in IdentityServer features.

Not redirect, but you can narrow the available Idp list for clients on server side by **IdentityProviderRestrictions**

**Client configuration on IdentityServer side**

```
new Client
{
    // serverside client configuration

    // ..

    IdentityProviderRestrictions = new string[]{"oidc"},

    // ...
}
```